# Solving non-linear ODE analytically in mathematica

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations

I would like to solve the following differential equations

$${dx\over dt}=\beta x-{{(C-x)^2}\over 4k} ,t\in[0, T]$$

where $\beta$,$C$ and $k$ are constant values. Also, the folowing terminal condition has to be satisfied
$$x(T)=0$$

is it possible to solve this analytically in Mathematica?

Thanks in advance

Comment: V10.1 solves it. Did you try it on your version and not get an answer?

Comment: @Nasser thanks for your comment. I don't have that version i use V9.0. but i'm not sure how to code it (specially with consideration of the terminal condition)

Comment: I do not know if there is any special thing to do, just type `x[T0]==0`, as in `ClearAll[beta, c, k, x, t];
eq = x'[t] == beta*x[t] - (c - x[t])^2/(4*k);
DSolve[{eq, x[T0] == 0}, x[t], t]` and I get this answer: ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/BFYCm.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And we Go:

```
ClearAll[b, c, k, x, t T0];

SOL = 
  First @
    Assuming[{b, c, k, T0} ∈ Reals, 
      DSolve[{x'[t] == b x[t] - (c - x[t])^2/(4 k), x[T0] == 0}, x[t], t]]; // Quiet

FullSimplify[SOL]
```

> $\left\{x(t)\to 2 \sqrt{b} \sqrt{k} \sqrt{b k+c} \tanh \left(\frac{\sqrt{b}
>    (t-\text{T0}) \sqrt{b k+c}}{2 \sqrt{k}}-\tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{2 b k+c}{2
>    \sqrt{b} \sqrt{k} \sqrt{b k+c}}\right)\right)+2 b k+c\right\}$